# what the major difference between PHP and ASP

Tags: php, asp.net, css

I have a freelance job which is based on CSS which is easy, but just need to know is there any major issues if I am a PHP developer and this is a ASP site i will be working on. Should I research any sites before i do anything on this job.

I take ASP still has class for css and that?

Comment: classic asp, or asp.net? There is a big difference between the two.

Comment: `confused` ASP (doesn't matter if its legacy or .net) has a class for css????

Comment: Are you sure that you want to take on this job with this much lack of understanding of fundamental matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the major difference?

[ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/) is a framework

[PHP](http://www.php.net/) is a language

Comment: @Alex R.: you don't know that for sure. Please take a look at the tags list

Comment: I did see the question was about css, but the question was posed as what is the difference between ASP.Net and PHP. Niether have anything to do with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Both are server side, and both output the same sort of end result. Since the CSS only applied to the end result, it should be fine as far as you're concerned.